# Auctex evince synchronization problematic with accented characters in file paths

Tags: emacs, auctex, knitr, forward-inverse-search, evince

I recently stumbled on this nice problem (bug ?):

I can use evince to visualize `foo.pdf` output from LaTeX obtained in AUCTeX and Synctex synchronization, as long as none of the files referenced in the synctex cross-reference file (`foo.synctex.gz`) have a pathname containing a non-ASCII character. Thanks to [this utility](https://github.com/jan-glx/patchKnitrSynctex), I can do the same thing with .Rnw files processed by knitr.

However, when my filename or the name of any referenced file contains an non-ASCII character, the process breaks down. Forward-search (C-C C-V in the TeX buffer) fails with a timeout on D-Bus (I'm running Linux with an `fr_FR.utf8` set of locales). Interestingly, backwards-search (Ctrl-click in the Evince window) tries to open the relevant `.tex` "source" in a non-existing directory in emacs, the said directory having the name of the original directory encoded in some fashion.

For example, if I'm working on `tTst.tex` in a directory named "Aquaphérèse", my Test.synctex.gz references the file

> Input:1:/home/charpent/Boulot/Aquaphérèse/./Test.tex", and when I try a bacward-search from evince, tex tries to create a buffer for " /home/charpent/Boulot/Aquaph%C3%A9r%C3%A8se/Test.tex".

This seems to me to be a bug either in AUCTeX or evince. Two questions :

1. What seems to you the most probable source of the problem: AUCTex
   (my personal hunch) or evince ?
2. Any suggestion for a workaround ? Of course, I can always rename my
   working tree, but that's a pain...

Any other suggestions welcome.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  Does this happen only with Evince (for which forward/inverse search is handled specially) or also with other viewers, e.g. Okular?  [This recent commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=ff1f544645c7b0f334b097bb8a9b1441fbf61b3e;hp=6e94ea0227aae5959b820b5021ef08973c2403eb) improved encoding of source path, but I cannot reproduce the bug with AUCTeX 11.88 neither.  I'd suggest you to report it to the AUCTeX developers with `M-x TeX-submit-bug-report RET`.

Comment: Your answer made me check : Debian testing still has 11.87.3. I installed 11.88 from unstable and got a different problem : starting with a .Rnw file processed with knitr, reverse-search (Ctl-click in PDF to get source) works (even in a directory whose name has accented chars), but forward-search (C-C C-V in the source buffer) fails wit the message : 'Output file "Meta1.Rnw.pdf" does not exist.', where Meta1 is my source .Rnw file. The problem does not occurs with a pure .tex file, for which forward-and backwards-search both work. Is this still worth reporting to AUCTex developpers ?

Comment: Try adding `rnw` to `TeX-file-extensions` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to myself :

1. As pointed out by giordano, the problem of handling non-ASCII characters in paths has been addressed in AUCTeX 11.88. It is not totally fixed (a message appears telling that  and  are the same file), but this is now functional.

(Note to Debian users : You'll have to get this from unstable : jessie is frozen).

2. The problem I had with forward-search is easily fixed by adding ".Rnw" to the list of recognized file extensions, TeX-file-extensions.

Now to [integration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219561/how-to-cleanly-post-process-pdf-compilation-in-auctex-and-ess) of this mess...

HTH